# AWS RDS Connection Best Practice

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, rds

I am looking to utilize AWS OpsWorks to deploy a PHP application utilizing a MySQL back-end. I have the PHP layer configured and built with some test PHP app deployed. I'm pondering between a normal MySQL back-end, or utilizing the AWS RDS MySQL back-end.

My question would be regarding the connectivity from the PHP front end servers to the back-end MySQL instance. What is the experience from users already doing this? Any gotchas to worry about? We currently develop locally using the typical db.php file containing the information to connect to the DB. Usually on the same server.

Anyone else doing something similar? Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

RDS is quite mature at this point, I strongly recommend using it instead of an EC2 instance with MySQL. In the long run it will help scale your application if your DB is the bottleneck in the architecture.

Comment: RDS is really simple and well designed. You should have no problems setting it up. The only thing that I've found "counter-intuitive" about RDS is that when you delete a RDS instance, it deletes all automatically created backups. Manually created backups are not deleted.

Comment: What about best practices for connecting the front-end to the RDS? Meaning, we currently use a db.php file to store the DB info (username, dbname, password, etc) and connect to it locally. Utilizing the OpsWorks RDS layer, it has it's own db info file to utilize. Just curious the best way to go about going from coding locally to putting up onto the OpsWorks layers with RDS.